# List all files in array with gulp.src()

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to create an index of all file(path)s within a given folder. So far I worked with `gulp.src(filePath)` to achieve that. According to this [blog post](http://jilles.me/introduction-to-gulp/), it should work:

> gulp.src(files) is a string or array containing the file(s) / file paths.

My current code:

```js
gulp.task("createFileIndex", function(){
    var index = gulp.src(['./content/**/*.*']);
    console.log("INDEX:", index[0]);
});
```

By outputing the returned values of `gulp.src()` with `index[0]` I get `undefined` and the whole `index` outputs only a large dictionary without any filepaths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the gulp documentation on **gulp.src** (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options)

> **gulp.src(globs[, options])**
>
> Emits files matching provided glob or an array of globs. Returns a
> stream of Vinyl files that can be piped to plugins.
>
> ```
> gulp.src('client/templates/*.jade')
>   .pipe(jade())
>   .pipe(minify())
>   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/minified_templates'));
> ```
>
> glob refers to node-glob syntax or it can be a direct file path.
>
> **globs**
>
> Type: String or Array
>
> Glob or array of globs to read.
>
> **options**
>
> Type: Object
>
> Options to pass to node-glob through glob-stream.
>
> gulp adds some additional options in addition to the options supported
> by node-glob and glob-stream

So it seems you need to look in further on this. Otherwise this maybe helpful [Get the current file name in gulp.src()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806925/get-the-current-file-name-in-gulp-src)

Comment: I created a workaround with nodejs' internal `js` library. `fs.readdirSync()` lists all files of a defined folder.

Answer (score 14):

The current solution is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');

gulp.src(sources)
  .pipe(debug());
```

Comment: This is the best answer: Avoids all unnecessary extra code and only shows the minimal code needed to test this functionality.

Answer (score 9):

As the OP stated in a comment, a simple solution to this problem would be to use [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) instead of `gulp.src`:

```
fs = require("fs");
fs.readdirSync(directoryPath); // ["file1", "file2"]
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
var through = require('through2');
gulp.task('getFileList', function () {
    var fileList = [];
    gulp.src(['./someFolder/**/*.ext', '!./someFolder/unwantedFolder/**/*'])
        .pipe(through.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
            fileList.push(file.path);
            cb(null);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp/'))
        .on ('end', function () {
            console.log(fileList);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is the array of filenames from a glob (like gulp.src) use:

```
const glob = require('glob');

const fileArray = glob.sync('./content/**/*.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use native Node.js function [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)

```
const fs = require('fs');

const syncImgFolder = (done) => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync('/path/');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do the following in gulp 4 :

```
gulp.src(['./lib/file3.js', './lib/file1.js', './lib/file2.js'])
```