# Globbing negation issue with Gulp

Tags: gulp, glob, negation

I am trying to match an entire folder structure of CSS files with the exception of a certain sub-folder and its included CSS files.

Consider this structure:

```
styles
    css
        thing1
            include.css
            include2.css
        thing2
            toBeExcluded
                exclude.css
                exclude2.css
```

In this example, I want to include the files `include.css` and `include2.css` but exclude the files inside the `thing2` sub-folder.

Here is the pattern I am using `gulp.src(["!./styles/css/thing2/", "!./styles/css/thing2/**/*.css", "./styles/css/**/*.css"])`

However, try as I might, I don't seem able to negate the `thing2` folder and it's files. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you try putting the negation part at the end, just change the sequence

Comment: You mean like: `gulp.src(["./styles/css/**/*.css", "!./styles/css/thing2/", "!./styles/css/thing2/**/*.css"])`? If so, I have already tried and same issue :(

Comment: Using gulp-debug (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21806974/1527470) and the same folder structure as yours:

`gulp-debug: styles/css/thing1/include copy.css`  
`gulp-debug: styles/css/thing1/include.css`  
`gulp-debug: 2 items`  

so it looks like your glob is working as expected.

Comment: thanks @dmnsgn I used debug and found I was still getting the files which confirmed I'd done something idiotic. I'd got a typo in my paths! Now working as expected!