# Gulp, using current filename in `pipe()` function

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to render each file in my gulp source files with it's own json file, but I can't figure out how to access the current filename in the `pipe` function.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var gulpHandlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');

gulp.task('compile-with-sample-data', function () {
  var options = {}
  return gulp.src('./src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulpHandlebars({ data: require('./data/' + filename +'.json') }, options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));

});
```

Where I can get it to work with the same file each time by just using `require('./data/orders-complete.json')`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var gulpHandlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');

gulp.task('compile-with-sample-data', function () {
  var options = {}
  return gulp.src('./src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulpHandlebars({ data: require('./data/orders-complete.json') }, options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));

});
```

It's not clear how I would do this.

Comment: Sounds like you need something like [gulp-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap/) to expose your file paths, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806925/get-the-current-file-name-in-gulp-src)

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? Can't achieve the desired effect with gulp-tap

Answer (score 4):

Use [gulp-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap), it enables you to get the file name and even change it for downstream pipes.