# debugging gulp glob patterns (node-glob)

Tags: build, gulp, node-glob, gulp-glob

I have a gulp task like this:

```
const dest_free = "build/free";

gulp.task("build-free", ["clean-free"], function () {
  gulp.src(["src/**", "!src/composer.*", "LICENSE", "src/plugins/index.php", "!src/plugins/**"])
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_free));
});
```

My dir structure:

```
$ ls -F src/plugins/
RecipeIndex/    VisitorRating/  index.php
```

I'm expecting `index.php` to be in `build/free/plugins/` but it's not:

```
$ ls -F build/free/plugins/
$
```

My questions:

1. How can I debug this issue, first of all? How would I get the result that the gulp glob is producing? Any article or material would be appreciated.
2. Why isn't `index.php` showing up in `build/free/plugins/`?

P.S.: Changing gulp glob order to this doesn't make a difference: `["src/**", "!src/composer.*", "LICENSE", "!src/plugins/**", "src/plugins/index.php"]`

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806925/get-the-current-file-name-in-gulp-src
You can use gulp-debug to get the files that the glob produces.

Comment: For your question 2, see this guy's excellent answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319426/gulp-exclude-does-not-work-as-expected/46326986#46326986.  Basically the negation is performed last, so your result with index.php not being included is the expected result.  See the referred question for options.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Cassidy Laidlaw's commment you can try the following, or the other options from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806925/get-the-current-file-name-in-gulp-src) previous post to debug:

```
var debug = require('gulp-debug');

gulp.task('build-free', ['clean-free'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/**', '!src/composer.*', 'LICENSE', 'src/plugins/index.php', '!src/plugins/**'])
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/free'));
});
```

This will output lines to the console like:

```
[22:23:05] gulp-debug: LICENSE
[22:23:05] gulp-debug: 1 item
```