# Gulp exclude does not work as expected

Tags: gulp, src

I have a gulp task that looks like this, just the `src` part:

```
gulp.src(
    [
    'site/bricks/global/global.scss',
    'site/bricks/**/*.scss',
    '!site/bricks/global/domain*.scss',
    'site/bricks/global/domain.mydomain.com.scss'
    ])
```

I expect it to do this:

- Load `global.scss` first (works)
- Load the rest of the scss files (works)
- Exclude all but domain (works)
- Include one of my domains back **(does not work)**

So for some reason I can't add a domain back to the list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that is expected behavior because all negation globs run **last**!  See [gulp.src negation order issues](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/837).

You have a few options though:

1.. Use gulp4.0 - supposed to be fixed there.

2.. [gulp-add-src](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src/) add that last file back in.

3.. [merge2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge2) create two separate streams and then merge them.