# Gulp is not overwriting the destination file

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, concatenation, overwrite

I've got a problem, regarding gulp. I decided to automate the process of how the source and styles are compiled into a single file, so I decided to use gulp for that purpose. However, it doesn't want to overwrite the `application.js` file that I'm creating from all `.js` files in my Project. The strange thing is that it actually overwrites the compiled css files, that is generated from all `.less` files in the Project.
Here is how my Project file structure looks like:

```
.
├── gulpfile.js
└── apps
    ├── base
        ├── controllers
            ├── controllerBaseOne.js
            └── controllerBaseTwo.js
        ├── directives
            ├── directiveBaseOne.js
            └── directiveBaseTwo.js
        ├── services
            └── serviceBaseOne.js
        └── styles
            └── styleBase.less
        ├── header.html
        └── index.html
    ├── services
        ├── compilation
            ├── application.js
            └── application.css
        ├── controllers
            ├── controllerServicesOne.js
            ├── controllerServicesTwo.js
            └── controllerServicesThree.js
        ├── directives
            ├── directiveServicesOne.js
            ├── directiveServicesTwo.js
            └── directiveServicesThree.js
        ├── services
            ├── serviceServicesOne.js
            └── serviceServicesTwo.js
        └── styles
            ├── styleServicesOne.less
            ├── styleServicesTwo.less
            └── styleServicesThree.less
        ├── header.html
        └── index.html
    ├── appMain.js
    └── config.json
```

Here is how my `gulpfile.js` looks now:

```
var gulp = require( "gulp" );
var gulpif = require( "gulp-if" );
var concat = require( "gulp-concat" );
var uglify = require( "gulp-uglify" );
var less = require( "gulp-less" );
var cleanCSS = require( "gulp-clean-css" );

// application components and paths:
var compileMinify = false;
var basePath = process.cwd() + "apps/base";
var webPath = process.cwd() + "apps/services";
var compilationPath = "compilation";
var appCompiledFileName = "application";
var stylePaths = [
    basePath + "/styles/**/*.less",
    webPath + "/styles/**/*.less"
];
var sourcePaths = [
    basePath + "/**/*.js",
    webPath + "/**/*.js"
];

gulp.task( "services-source", function() {
    return gulp.src( sourcePaths )
        .pipe( concat( appCompiledFileName + ".js" ) )
        .pipe( gulpif( compileMinify, uglify() ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( compilationPath, { cwd: webPath } ) );
} );
gulp.task( "services-styles", function() {
    return gulp.src( stylePaths )
        .pipe( concat( appCompiledFileName + ".less" ) )
        .pipe( less() )
        .pipe( gulpif( compileMinify, cleanCSS( { debug: true }, function( details ) {
            console.log( details.name + " original size: " + details.stats.originalSize );
            console.log( details.name + " minified size: " + details.stats.minifiedSize );
        } ) ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( compilationPath, { cwd: webPath } ) );
} );
gulp.task( "services", [ "services-source", "services-styles" ], function() {
    gulp.watch( sourcePaths, [ "services-source" ] );
    gulp.watch( stylePaths, [ "services-styles" ] );
} );
```

As you can see, the gulp task `services-source` is going through each `.js` file in the `apps` folder and sub-folders, and concatenate all into a single file that should be put into `compilation` folder. Same is done in the `services-styles` task, just some less transformation is made. There is also a check to minify both styles and sources, but it's disabled by default for now.

I tried adding at the end of the `services-source` task, where you put the destination of the complied file a parameter for overwriting like so: `overwrite: true`, but nothing seems to happen. When I run the `gulpfile.js` it makes just the `application.js` bigger and bigger each time - it's not overwriting it somehow.

So, any advice what can be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your application.js  file is being included in your src when you start the task each time.

You could try using a plugin such as [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug/) to log out the current file in the stream to confirm. [(See this answer for that)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21806974/4797198)

If that's the cause you can then explicitly exclude it:

```
var sourcePaths = [
  "!path/to/application.js",
  basePath + "/**/*.js",
  webPath + "/**/*.js"
];
```

Comment: You man, just saved my life! I spent like 3 hours thinking what could be the issue, and that's what it was - `compilation` folder was also included in the task each time... So added this as well to the `sourcePaths` array:
`"!" + webPath + "/" + compilationPath + "/**/*.js"`

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

try below one

gulp.src("sourcefilepath")
      .pipe("destinationdirpath", { overwrite: false }))