# Gulp - apply gulp-version-number plugin every time on .html, which will never change

Tags: javascript, gulp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Node plugin (Gulp v.4) normally overwrites files, but in this case, he will not overwrite file in the destination folder, why?

```
function rew_front() {
    return gulp.src( [ assets_front + '*.html'] )
        .pipe(version({
            'value' : '%DT%',
            'append' : {
                'key' : 'v',
                'cover' : 0,
                'to' : [
                    'css',
                    'js'
                ]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.latte',
        }))
        .pipe(cleanDest( app_front, {extension: '.latte'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( app_front ))
}
```

Even when I add new plugin for clearing destination folder, which it should first delete all files in the destination folder, then that function `rew_front` should create new files, but it not works.

If I will delete these files in destination folder by myself, and then I run `rew_front` function, it will create correctly new files, but only this way.

Why it's not working? Is there a problem with PhpStorm, some kind of settings?

Update:

I found that problem is in pipe and plugin `gulp-version-number`, where is applied version plugin, that plugin change every .html only, if MD5 is changed, but I need apply rewrite version everytime, even if .html is not change at all, just simply still changing version in links whenever I run that function

```
version         = require( 'gulp-version-number' ),
.pipe(version({
                'value' : '%DT%',
                'append' : {
                    'key' : 'v',
                    'cover' : 0,
                    'to' : [
                        'css',
                        'js'
                    ]
                }
            }))
```

Comment: it's unlikely a PhpStorm issue, it's not PhpStorm that executes your function. Does your gulp task work when you run it in terminal?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959037/gulp-is-not-overwriting-the-destination-file

Comment: @lena yes, I found that problem is in .pipe(version... where that plugin version only change file if source file is changed, but source file will be still same, so I need something to approve change file and apply on it function .pipe(version... every time even if that file will never change

Comment: @lena that problem is not mine, its something else