# Gulp watch callback task not firing

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-task

I'm trying to set up a gulp-watch which triggers a gulp task when some files change. For this purpose I'm using the following code:

```
gulp.task('watchChanges', function(cb){
    console.log("Looking for file changes in " + watchPath+".");  

    return watch(watchPath, ['FilesChanged']);
});

gulp.task('FilesChanged', function (cb){
    FilesChanged();
    cb();
})

function FilesChanged()
{
    console.log("Files changed:")
}
```

Whenever the files change I would like it if the 'FilesChanged' task would fire and I'd see the "Files changed:" text in console. This doesn't happen.

When I change my watchChanges task to this:

```
gulp.task('watchChanges', function(cb){
    console.log("Looking for file changes in " + watchPath+".");  

    return watch(watchPath, FilesChanged);
});
```

Can anyone explain why the first piece of code does not execute correctly?

Comment: Do you have your own watch function that you are calling or do intend to use gulp.watch?  If you have a watch function what does it look like?  Are you using gulp-watch there?  We need more information.  Gulp-watch can be passed a function as you have it in the working example but not a list of task names.

Comment: @Mark I am using gulp-watch. I forgot to include a part of my code in the example:
`var gulp = require('gulp');

var watch = require('gulp-watch');`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using gulp-watch if you look at its function definition:

> watch(glob, [options, callback])

you can see that it will take a callback function which is why your

> return watch(watchPath, FilesChanged);

works and

> return watch(watchPath, ['FilesChanged']);

does not.  gulp-watch will not take an array of tasks like gulp.watch will:

> gulp.watch(glob[, opts], tasks)

gulp-watch and gulp.watch are two entirely different things.  What you probably want is

```
gulp.task('watchChanges', function(cb){
    console.log("Looking for file changes in " + watchPath+".");  

    gulp.watch(watchPath, ['FilesChanged']);
});
```

If you then to see which files are being processed, try one of the suggestions from [get the current file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806925/get-the-current-file-name-in-gulp-src?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had indeed looked over the function defintions for watch and gulp-watch.

I have correct my code to your last example but I still do not get the required result.

So this works:
`watch(watchPath, FilesChanged)
            .pipe(debug());`


But this does not:
`gulp.watch(watchPath, ['FilesChanged'])
            .pipe(debug());`